# Creating a clickable grid scheduling-like tool thing for D365 MDA on CDS

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, common-data-service, powerapps-modeldriven

I'd love to be able to create an interactive something like the picture below to include in an app - rows represent partners that we'd work with, and columns represent how many widgets they are assigned to build per month (those numbers come from the partner based on their resources, availability, etc.) The goal is to track how many of the expected widgets were created, how many were started and cancelled, etc. according to how mnay "slots" were allocated. Clicking on a "box" would cycle through the colors to indicate the status of that widget. All data would be stored in the underlying CDS entities.

This UI is familiar to my team, which is currently based in Excel, but want to transfer into a custom widget I can surface in our Model-driven App in CDS.

Any suggestions on a web UI framework/approach/etc. to help me get started? I don't want to recreate something that already exists somewhere, or start building from scratch something that there is a cool (yet unknown to me) UI framework that would make this easier than starting from complete scratch.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[PowerApps component framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/overview) is the way to go. Typescript is the language to be developed on and Dynamics context awareness is main plus for this PCF control.

As far as I know, there is no control available for this. [Check here](https://pcf.gallery/)

[PCF builder](https://powermaverick.dev/2019/10/07/pcf-custom-control-builder/) is a good place to start the development.